# Memory-mapped files: pros and cons?

Tags: java, ipc, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

I need to share data between two Java applications running on the same machine (two different JVMs). I precise that the data to be shared is large (about 7 GB). The applications must access the data very fast because they have to answer incoming queries at a very high rate. I don't want the applications to hold each one a copy of the data.

I've seen that one option is to use memory-mapped files. Application A gets the data from somewhere (let's say a database) and stores it in files. Then application B may access these files using `java.nio`. I don't know exactly how memory-mapped files work, I only know that the data is stored in a file and that this file (or a part of it) is mapped to a region of the memory (virtual memory?). So, the two applications can read-write the data in memory and the changes are automatically (I guess?) committed to the file. I also don't know if there is a maximum size for a file to be entirely mapped in memory.

My first question is what are the different possibilities for two applications to share data in this scenario (I mean taking into account that the amount of data is very large and that access to this data must be very fast)? I precise that this question is not related to memory-mapped I/O, it just to know what are the other ways to solve the same problem.

My second question is what are the pros and cons of using memory-mapped files?

Thanks

Comment: can u also provide details, how exactly you want to use memory mapped files?

Comment: I see the question is not about triggering of some action in oth other program. If so Why not a common database to share data?

Comment: @Pangea I have time access constraints, the applications must access the data rapidly.

Comment: What part of this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication fails to answer your question?  Can be specific on what more you need than what's already widely available?

Comment: @S.Lott I've read the wikipedia page but that's my question. I guess there are some solutions that don't fit well to my case?

Comment: "I guess there are some solutions that don't fit well to my case?"  That's not true.  All the IPC communication techniques in the wikipedia article work for your case.  You chose one of many.  The article describes all of them quite nicely.  It's not clear what confuses you and what more you need to know.  Can you expand or clarify your question?  Can you quote specific parts of the wikipedia article that confuse you or seem incomplete?

Comment: @S.Lott File method don't fit well because access is slow. Signal method is irrelevant. Socket method, I guess it's also slow?and not good for such amount of data? Shared memory, i didn't find that it's possible in Java between two JVMs. The rest I don't know what they are. So, there are many solutions but certain don't fit well with my requirements.

Comment: "there are many solutions but certain don't fit well with my requirements".  False.  Files are not slow.  They are very fast.  You can share physical files quickly.  Sockets are fast, also, and work with vast amounts of data.  Shared memory is what a memory-mapped file actually is.  The rest are worth studying.  What is it you want to know?  Can you be specific?

Comment: @S.Lott I've added "more details" to the question. I'm trying to find a solution to my problem: two applications A and B that need data to answer queries at a very high rate. An application C gets the data from the database, and at this point, I want this data to be shared between the application A, B and C. Also, C may update the data periodically, and I want the changes to be visible for A and B. The amount of data is very large. I want that all applications may access the data as faster as possible. Also, I don't want all the applications to hold a copy of the data.

Comment: @MickaelMarrache: If that's your question, the ask **that** and **only that** and **nothing more**.  A vague "pros and cons" is very hard to answer.  Your specific application can be done with **ANY** interprocess communication.  **ANY**.  What do you want to know?  Do you want something other than memory-mapped files?  Why?  What's wrong with the solution you have now?  It works, right?  If it works, what more do you want to know?

Comment: @S.Lott I'm just thinking about a "good" way to do this. I understand that it can be done with ANY interprocess communication, but only providing communication isn't enough for me. I also need good performances. I agree that all allow the processes to communicate but not all with the best performances. I don't understand your comments. I think my question is clear, I've added precision as I can.

Comment: I'll try to be clear.  They all work.  They're all good.  They're all fast.  All of them.  The differences in performance are rather minor.  Indeed, many IPC's (like memory-mapped files) depend on other IPC's.  Memory-mapped file is the same as shared memory.  They're just different metaphors for thinking about locks and shared  data.  Does your memory-mapped file work?  If yes, what more do you want to know?  If no, please explain how it is failing to work so we can suggest solutions.  Randomly providing "better" than what you have is impossible.

Comment: @S.Lott Let's take as example the sockets. Application A gets data from application B using sockets. Each time a query is received by A, it sends a query to B (using sockets) to get the needed data. Then, when the data is received, it can answer the query. That's a possibility. In this case, only the application B stores the data, so it's good for me. But what about the case A receives 10 Kqps? It needs to request the data 10K times using sockets. Do you think it's more efficient that the case A can access directly a region in memory to get the needed data?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache: What?  If that's your question, please write in as a question.  Please don't write a question in the comments.  Your example doesn't make much sense, since sockets are the backbone of the internet and 10K requests are perfectly normal and common.  Socket requests on the same computer are amazingly fast.  Please form your question about sockets as a complete question about sockets.

Comment: @S.Lott I understand that sockets on the same machine are fast, but because there are many mechanisms to do the same thing, I wanted to know if there is one better than other for my case. If you say that all the mechanisms fit with my case (and are all fast), how can I make a decision? I'm pretty sure that there are some of them that fit well in some cases, and other with other cases (even if all work in my case). This is a simple question.

Comment: "This is a simple question".  False.  It's not a question at all.  "how can I make a decision?"  Is that your **real** question?  Then ask that question.  Please try to ask something we can answer.  All IPC's work.  All are fast.  The difference is one of convenience.   You pick one that makes your design simple and logical.  95% of the time a message queue is perfect for most purposes.  If that what you're asking?  How to switch to a message queue?  What do you want to know?  **Do you have a design that works?** **What SPECIFIC problem do you have?**  Please give us something to answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> My first question is what are the different possibilities for two applications to share data?

As S.Lott points out, there's a *lot* of mechanisms:

- OS-level [message queues](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/msgctl.html)
- OS-level [POSIX shared memory segments](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/shmctl.html) (persist after process death)
- OS-level [memory mappings](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html) (could be anonymous or file-backed)
- OS-level [anonymous pipes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pipe.html) (unidirectional)
- OS-level [named pipes](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/fifo.7.html) (unidirectional)
- OS-level [sockets](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/socket.html) (bidirectional) -- whether [`AF_UNIX`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/unix.7.html) or [`AF_INET`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/tcp.7.html) or [`AF_INET6`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/ipv6.7.html)
- OS-level [shared global memory](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) -- suitable for multi-threaded programs
- Storing data in files
- Application-level [message queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol)
- Application-level [blackboard-style tuplespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linda_(coordination_language))
- Application-level [key/value stores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached)
- Application-level [remote procedure call frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_RMI) -- [many are available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corba)
- Application-level [web-based frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST)

> My second question is what are the pros and cons of using memory-mapped files?

Pros:

- very fast -- depending upon how you access the data, potentially [zero-copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy) mechanisms can be used to operate directly on the data with no speed penalties. Care must be taken to update objects in a *consistent manner*.
- should be very portable -- available on Unix systems for probably 25 years (give or take), [and apparently Windows has mechanisms too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory).

Cons:

- Single-system sharing. If you want to distribute your application over multiple machines, shared memory isn't a great option. [Distributed shared memory systems are available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_shared_memory), but they feel very much like the wrong interface to my way of thinking.
- Even on a single system, if the memory is located on a single [NUMA node](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Uniform_Memory_Access) but needed to be accessed by processors from multiple nodes, the inter-node requests may significantly slow processing compared to giving each node their own segment of the memory.
- You can't just store pointers -- everything must be stored as *offsets* to base addresses, because the memory may be mapped at different locations in different processes. I have no idea what this means for Java objects, though presumably someone smart did their best to make it transparent to Java programmers. If you're not using their provided mechanisms, then you probably must do the work yourself. (Without actual *pointers* in Java, perhaps this is not very onerous.)
- Updating objects consistently has proven to be very difficult. Passing [immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable) in message-passing systems instead generally results in programs with fewer concurrency bugs. (Concurrent programming in [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)) feels very natural and straight-forward. Concurrent programming in more [imperative languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_languages) tends to introduce a huge pile of new concurrency controls: [semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)), [mutexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex), [spinlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock), [monitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization))).

Comment: Thanks sarnold for the detailed answer. What about the OS-level solutions and portability? When you say application-level, you mean that it is handled by the JVM and it's portable?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache: by "application-level" I mean that you, as the application author, have to the provide the infrastructure, whether it is running RabbitMQ, Linda, Memcached, CORBA, or a RESTful web service. (Whether they can run in the same JVM is another matter entirely.) All the OS-level services are provided by the operating system -- which might mean you need to use [extra modules](http://bmsi.com/java/posix/index.html) to use them natively.

Answer (score 1):

Memory mapped files sounds like a headache. A simple option and less error prone would be to use a shared database with a cluster aware cache. That way only writes go down to the database and reads can be served from the cache.

As an example of how to do this in hibernate see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache